# How can i return error messages as select statement SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

In SQL SERVER 2008 how can i return error messages as select statement

*LIKE*

```
SELECT ** FROM emp
```

*Will return the following error*

```
    Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
    Incorrect syntax near '*'.
```

i just need the 2nd line to be returned as `SELECT` statement

I've tried @@ERROR but looks like it return just the error code

What i'm doing is validating sql statements from the client side, so if there is a way of doing this with out hitting the server this will be good too i'm using VB

Thanks

Comment: What context are you trying to use this in? Can you catch the error message in the client code?

Comment: no i can't i was trying but i couldn't find any thing to do this in the client side

Comment: RE: Without hitting the server. Depending on your needs [Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do see `Incorrect syntax near '*'.`, don't you? That means **it was returned**!

You may want to know how to retrieve the error message(s) text, and the answer is that you can only capture error that occur during *execution* (syntax errors are compilation and cannot be captured inside the same batch) and you must use the BEGIN ... TRY/ BEGIN ... CATCH block. Inside a catch block the [`ERROR_MESSAGE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190358.aspx) function will return the text of the exception caught.

So, to give an example base don your case, wrap the code in a BEGIN TRY/BEGIN CATCH and have the incorrect syntax in a different batch:

```
begin try
    exec sp_executesql N'SELECT ** FROM emp';
    SELECT NULL;
end try
begin catch
    select ERROR_MESSAGE();
end catch
```

Comment: `What i'm doing is validating sql statements from the client side` that is a very very very different question from what you asked... You can't. There is no way to validate T-SQL outside using a SQL Server. You can parse a statement w/o executing using [`SET PARSEONLY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178629.aspx)

Comment: can you tell me how can i return null when the statement is valid ? Thanks

Comment: See the modified example. The SELECT NULL is only executed if no exception is raised.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `error_message()`

but your error looks like compile error, so it will not help you. You can catch it only if you'll use dynamic SQL :)
Just to test it

```
begin try
    exec sp_executesql
        @stmt = N'SELECT ** FROM emp'
end try
begin catch
    select error_message()
end catch
```

Also you can take a look at `error_procedure()`, `error_line()`, `error_state()` and so on

**UPDATE** If you're trying to handle server errors at your client, I suggest you to read more about VB exceptions. 
Try this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289505(v=vs.71).aspx